# Adding Captcha to a django login form

Tags: python, django, django-views, recaptcha, django-login

I would like to add Captcha authentication to my Django login. I already know how to authenticate the form but the problem is that i don't have a login View on my **views.py**, i'm using the login view of a module that i integrated on my project.

The login view that i'm using is right [here](https://github.com/Bouke/django-two-factor-auth/blob/master/two_factor/views/core.py), and basically i just imported it on my project and that view handles the whole login part.

Now how can i add a captcha authentication part to that view?

I know that the first thing i should do is inherit the  module's view on my own **views.py** file, but i don't really know how to go from here. I already defined the authentication logic of the Captcha form, so the only thing i need to figure out is how to integrate the following code into the login view that i'm using:

```
def captcha_auth(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        ''' Begin reCAPTCHA validation '''
        recaptcha_response = request.POST.get('g-recaptcha-response')
        data = {
            'secret': 'KEY',
            'response': recaptcha_response
        }
        r = requests.post('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify', data=data)
        result = r.json()
        ''' End reCAPTCHA validation '''

        if result['success']:
            //In the following lines i'll add authentication for the user

        else:
            messages.error(request, "Please fill the captcha form")
```

Comment: I'd recommend using this repo https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha

Comment: I would suggest you to take a look at this https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/02/21/how-to-add-recaptcha-to-django-site.html  or follow the google docs